# ¿Cómo consumir WCF (Webservice de C#) en una aplicación de angular 4?

Tags: c#, angular

Buen día. He estado investigando bastante en la red, y he creado ya mi webservice en C#, pero no he encontrado la manera de consumir mi servicio en angular 4. 
¿Alguien tendrá alguna información al respecto? Gracias.

He aquí mi código del WCF:

```
 public class Service1 : IService1
 {
    // NOTA: puede usar el comando "Rename" del menú "Refactorizar" para cambiar el nombre de clase "Service1" en el código, en svc y en el archivo de configuración.
    // NOTE: para iniciar el Cliente de prueba WCF para probar este servicio, seleccione Service1.svc o Service1.svc.cs en el Explorador de soluciones e inicie la depuración.
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source = ******; initial catalog = Prueba; user id = sa; password = ****");

        //Método para hacer un Login
        public string ValidateLogin(string usuario, string pass)
        {
            string mensaje = "";
            List<string> UsuarioPassword = new List<string>();
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tb_c_usuarios 
                where usuario=@usuario and pass=@pass", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    mensaje = "Usuario encontrado";

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string nombreUsuario = dt.Rows[i] 
                         ["usuario"].ToString();
                        string password = dt.Rows[i]["pass"].ToString();

                        UsuarioPassword.Add(nombreUsuario);
                        UsuarioPassword.Add(password);
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    mensaje = "No hubo coincidencias";
                }

                con.Close();
            }
            return mensaje;
        }
```

Comment: Despues de usar webservices me decidi por websockets es bastante compatible con varios lenguajes de programacion en mi caso lo utilizo con node y Java pero es posible con C# aqui podras encontrar alguna idea; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200910/creating-a-hello-world-websocket-example

Comment: Gracias, le echaré un vistazo.